# Ignore nil properties when serializing JSON using RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I have this class:

```
@interface MovieStatus : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* seen;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* watchlist;
@end
```

Where both properties represent optional nullable boolean values. I'm sending this object to the server using RestKit through the `RKObjectManager` and created the appropriate mapping. But I'm unable to skip the property from the POST data when serializing the object.

For example, this code:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("*", RKLogLevelTrace);

RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/v1"]];
manager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

RKObjectMapping* requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"seen", @"watchlist"]];

RKRequestDescriptor* requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[MovieStatus class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

RKRoute* route = [RKRoute routeWithClass:[MovieStatus class] pathPattern:@"status" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:route];


MovieStatus* status = [[MovieStatus alloc] init];
status.seen = @(YES);
[manager postObject:status path:nil parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

is sending the JSON:

```
{
  "seen": true,
  "watchlist": null
}
```

Where I'd like to send:

```
{
  "seen": true
}
```

Can anyone point me out how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it by setting the `assignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes` of the mapping to `NO`:

```
requestMapping.assignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = NO;
```

Now the JSON request doesn't contain `null` values.

Comment: Is there anyway to set this globally instead of individually for each mapping?

Comment: You could subclass RKObjectMapping

Comment: This didn't work for me, and I also thought that this was meant to be set to `NO` by default?
I've posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846262/how-do-i-ignore-empty-properties-on-posted-objects-using-restkit

Comment: There is a similar property assignsNilForMissingRelationships. Just be aware of that.